# LInq to Sql query with Group by

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to write a linq to sql query equivalent to the following sql query:

```
select * from [TableA]
INNER JOIN (select C1, COUNT(*) C2 FROM [Table2] GROUP BY C1) av ON [TableA].C1 = av.C1
WHERE av.C2 > 10
```

Can any one please help me how to write equivalent link query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = from b in context.TableB
             group new { c1 } by new
             {
                b.c1
             } into GroupByC1
             select new 
             {
                c1 = GroupByC1.Key.C1,
                count1 = GroupByC1.count()
             } 

var result = from a in tableA
             join b in query on a.c1 equals b.c1
             where b.count1 > 10
```